# Resizing a p:ring

Tags: jsf, primefaces, size

Is there anyway to resize the [`<p:ring>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/ring.xhtml)? I tried with "width" and "height" but it didn't work. The windows are always small and I want them bigger.

This is the XHTML code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/template/templatePCD1.xhtml"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

    <ui:define name="pageTitle">Groupe details</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="pageContent" >
        <h:form id="form" >
            <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Groupe details</h3>
            <p:ring id="custom" value="#{allGroupeBean.groupes}" var="car" >
                <p:panel >
                    <p:column  >

                        <p:panelGrid columns="1"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.nom}"  />
                            <p:commandButton update=":form:carDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show();"  >
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target=" #{allGroupeBean.selectedGroupe}"  />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:column>
                    <br/>
                </p:panel>
            </p:ring>

            <p:dialog header="Groupe Info" widgetVar="carDialog" modal="true"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" width="470">
                <p:outputPanel id="carDetail" style="text-align:center;" layout="block">
                    <p:dataTable id="selectedCarsTable" var="car" value="# {allGroupeBean.selectedGroupe.teams}">
                        <p:column headerText="Teams">
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.nom}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Points">
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.point}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

It shows small windows and I need bigger ones.

Comment: I think you have to customize the CSS (try .ui-ring { width: x%; } (default is 70% I think)

Comment: where do I put  class="ui-ring" in the html code?

Comment: you don't. You have to refer to an external css using h:outputStylesheet

Comment: may be some other CSS too, you have to tweak yourself. Add some firefox plugin that let you inspect and change the CSS